# Is there beforeAll method in Cucumber?

Tags: automation, protractor, cucumber, ui-automation

I want not a hook but real beforeAll method where I can pass my code like:

```
Feature: someething
BeforeAll:
    doThis
    doThat

Background:
    soSomethingElse

Scenario1:
Scenario2:

AfterAll:
    deleteThis
    deleteThat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing for CucumberJS